# How to change the Node JS Version in Azure Functions local project

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions

Created the Azure Functions Node JS Version 19 which is not yet supported for the Azure Functions as I come to know from this [Microsoft Documentation](https://aka.ms/functions-node-versions).

I know we can change the Node Version in Azure Function App Configuration.
But this is after deployment.

**How to change the Node JS Version to 18 from 19 before deployment, in local solution/project - VS Code?**

I tried to check the two attributes such as `linuxFxVersion`,`WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` which are not found/visible in the local project code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have reproduced your issue by creating the latest version of Node JS i.e., 19.5 with Azure Functions locally in the VS Code IDE:

[image]

To change the Node JS Version in Local Azure Function Project, you have to uninstall the latest version from the system and install the required version of the Node JS as specified in the Question is version 18.

Installable Source - https://nodejs.org/es/blog/release/v18.12.0

Then Restart the VS Code > Open your Node JS Version 19.5 Azure Functions Project > Open Terminal and use the below commands:

```js
nvm ls
nvm install 18.12.0
nvm use 18.12.0
```

[image]

Comment: Hey @PravallikaKV, Thanks for the step-by-step process.